# How to remove the properties of map in neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I'm looking for a way to delete the properties of map from a node in neo4j.
I have Stored the properties of a map in node using **@Properties** in my class. which stored the values in the node. my node looks like this. [image]

But when i am going to remove the property of the description.ENGLISH it gives me the error . which is given in the graph.

This is my Domain.

```
public class Test  {


private String name;



@Properties
private Map<LanguageEnum,String> description;
//getter and setter}
```

And this is my Query to remove  **description.ENGLISH** from node.

```
MATCH (n:Test{moduleId:"tab_201"}) remove n.description.ENGLISH return n
```

**NOTE**: I am unable to update the value as well via CQL.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cypher, you can use the backtick (`) character to quote property keys (as well as labels and types) that contain special characters (like "."). For example:

```
MATCH (n:Test{moduleId:"tab_201"}) remove n.`description.ENGLISH` return n
```